# How to changes user name(account) in WOS2 identity server?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I would like to know that is possible to change user account in UM_USER table with by an API client stub so as RemoteUserService or AdminService in WSO2 identity server 5.1. or else, exist any solutions that can changes username

thanks for your cooperation

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported OOTB. You can try [this](http://tharindue.blogspot.com/2015/05/a-workaround-for-renaming-username-of.html) alternative solution.